# Connect to Azure MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I'm trying out Azure for the first time. I followed [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/) guide to create a web application with a MySQL database.

So the DB node was create and I can see it in my resources and I can view the credentials in the properties. However, I can't connect to it from my desktop.

It looks like a firewall issue as I'm unable to telnet to it:

```
telnet us-cdbr-azure-west-c.cloudapp.net 3306
Trying 104.209.43.4...
telnet: connect to address 104.209.43.4: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you setup clearDB for MySQL in azure?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I clicked create as shown in the guide. I can see my database and a green tick beside it in the clearDB dashboard.

Comment: Is your application running? And are you using MySQL workbench to connect it from your desktop?

Comment: Yes application is running. I've tried workbench, then connecting via the terminal with mysql and then I tried connecting over TCP with telnet which indicates the node isn't reachable.

Comment: I could telnet to it, it looks like you changed the blank root password though :(  I think you have a firewall issue on your side.

Comment: Same here, I can telnet your MySQL Db

Comment: Are you under a firewall protected network?, or Maybe are you using some local firewall software kind of McAfee shield or similar? If so, just disabled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, this issue is raised due to `IP` or `Port` is blocked by firewall.

As the comments show that others can connect to your MySQL server, so I think we can exclude that server side firewall blocked your `IP` and `Port`.

If you are in a protect network environment, check whether the gateway of network has a white list and your MySQL server endpoint is in the list, or whether the gateway has block the 3306 port. You can change a network environment if possible to check this.

Another attempt is that you can change a PC to have a test to connect to your MySQL server. If it could work, you can compare with the successful PC firewall configuration.